# Not able to use JWT token for loading Mapkit for authorization

Tags: jwt, mapkit, mapkit-js

I am trying to load CAD image from geojson files using MapKit.js library.
For authorization of geolocation I am using JWT to generate the token, as listed below.

```
import jwt import time

#https://github.com/addisonwebb/Apple-JWT-Generator
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfKatqbZicA

# Team ID team_id = 'AAAAAAAAAA'

# Key ID key_id = 'BBBBBBBBBBBB'

# Private Key private_key = b'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----' issued_timestamp = time.time()

encoded = jwt.encode({'iss': team_id,'iat': issued_timestamp}, private_key, algorithm='ES256', headers={'kid': key_id}) print(encoded)
```

I see the below issue when tried to use JWT token generated from the above code.

```
[MapKit] Initialization failed because the authorization token is invalid.
```

Can someone please help.